# Session object cannot be deserialized

Tags: xdb, session-state

I'm getting the following error in my logs and at the same time experiencing data loss into xDB. 
This is on `Sitecore 8.2 update 5`.

My logs show following error:

> 9612 11:44:56 WARN  Failed to deserialize Session object.
>   Exception: **Sitecore.Analytics.Exceptions.TypeNotAllowedForBindingException**
>   Message: **Binding for type Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.NextPageData from assembly Sitecore.Analytics, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null is not allowed.**
>   Source: Sitecore.Analytics
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Sessions.WhitelistSerializationBinder.BindToType(String assemblyName, String typeName)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Bind(String assemblyString, String typeString)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Sessions.PushSession.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

I tried adding this to `sessionSerialization/allowedTypes`, but this just caused next on to occur:

> 9648 11:23:11 WARN  Failed to deserialize Session object.
>   Exception: **Sitecore.Analytics.Exceptions.TypeNotAllowedForBindingException**
>   Message: **Binding for type Sitecore.Analytics.Model.OperatingSystemData from assembly Sitecore.Analytics.Model, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null is not allowed**.
>   Source: Sitecore.Analytics
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Sessions.WhitelistSerializationBinder.BindToType(String assemblyName, String typeName)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Bind(String assemblyString, String typeString)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
>      at Sitecore.Analytics.Sessions.PushSession.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

These are out of the Box Sitecore types, so I would not expect me to have to add them to allowedTypes. Also, adding multiple types here in a patch files does not seem to work, only the first added type is working, I have to add them to the original `Sitecore.Analytics.SessionSerialization.config` files, which is totally unacceptable. But as I don't find anyone else complaining about this, I wonder if I am doing something wrong to cause this.

I appreciate any insights here.

Comment: Patching succeeded by just deleting allowedTypes element in its totality, and replacing it. But this is not a future proof solutions for when new Sitecore versions appear.

Answer (score 4):

As you pointed out on your comment, this can be resolved by adding the missing types `Sitecore.Analytics.SessionSerialization.config`. You can see Sitecore comes with a bunch of these by default. Maybe they missed couple of them?

You should be able to patch this list, but you need to add a unique attribute to each node so they don't replace each other. e.g. (see `desc` attribute)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
<sessionSerialization>
  <!-- Provides fully qualified type names, which are allowed to be serialized. -->
  <allowedTypes>
    <type desc="a">MyAssembly.MyType.aaaa, MyAssembly</type>
    <type desc="b">MyAssembly.MyType.bbbb, MyAssembly</type>
  </allowedTypes>
</sessionSerialization>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thnx that indeed fixes the patching part. Will create a support ticket with Sitecore and updat this thread on whether indeed they forgot these types

Answer (score 0):

This has been registered as a bug at Sitecore. My workaround is correct until a patch is delivered or the bug is fixed in future releases.